# Can spark be configured to infer an empty dataset to an empty schema

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

We have lots of parquet datasets partitioned over year/month/day/hour.

A few of these hours are empty having just a single `_SUCCESS` file.

We implement jobs that iterate over all partitions and perform work. We run into issues when opening empty datasets. Crashing with `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Unable to infer schema for Parquet. It must be specified manually.`

(using EMR5.3.0 - we are working to rid ourselves of a dependency so that we can upgrade to later version)

Spark-shell example:

```
Welcome to
      ____              __
    / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
  /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.1.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_121)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val df = spark.read.parquet("s3://some-bucket/empty-dataset/")
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Unable to infer schema for Parquet. It must be specified manually.;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$8.apply(DataSource.scala:189)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$8.apply(DataSource.scala:189)
```

As spark says I can specify a schema but that is impractical for me as the schema is large and differs per partition (don't ask).

My preferred solution would be if spark could be configured to infer empty datasets into empty schemas.

Comment: Hi. Make this the answer and I accept it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally `spark.read.parquet` should take param `ignoreEmptyFiles=true`, unfortunately this was not supported.

The best you can do is, before reading filter the empty directories